# Export Video Processing Video Applet

Tags: java, video, processing

I am facing a recurrent problem when I try to export a Processing applet that deals with video to work in the browser. It's a simple application that stops, plays and pauses a .mp4 video. When I run it using Processing IDE, it works just fine. But executing the index.html generated when I export, the video box gets blank and nothing happen and I get this error in the console:

```
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class quicktime.QTSession
    at processing.video.Movie.init(Unknown Source)
    at processing.video.Movie.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at processing.video.Movie.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sketch_nov14a.setup(sketch_nov14a.java:31)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(Unknown Source)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Maybe it is a known issue, but I still can't find the solution: [BUG 44](http://processing.org/bugs/bugzilla/44.html)

That is the code:

```
import processing.video.*;

Movie theMov; 
boolean isPlaying;
boolean isLooping;


void setup() { 
  size(600,400,P2D);
  theMov = new Movie(this, "http://www.sinopsedofilme.com.br/processing/video2.mp4");
  /* only use 1 of the following options */
  theMov.play();  //plays the movie once
  theMov.loop();  //plays the movie over and over
  isPlaying = true;
  isLooping = true;

}

void draw() { 
  image(theMov, 0,0); 
} 

void movieEvent(Movie m) { 
  m.read(); 
} 

void keyPressed() {
  if (key == 'p') {
    // toggle pausing
    if (isPlaying) {
      theMov.pause();
    } else {
      theMov.play();
    }
    isPlaying = !isPlaying;

  } else if (key == 'l') {
    // toggle looping
    if (isLooping) {
      theMov.noLoop();
    } else {
      theMov.loop();
    }
    isLooping = !isLooping;

  } else if (key == 's') {
    // stop playing
    theMov.stop();
    isPlaying = false;

  } else if (key == 'j') {
    // jump to a random time
    theMov.jump(random(theMov.duration()));
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, the joy of libraries without debug info :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Debugging tips](http://processing.org/discourse/yabb/YaBB.cgi?board=general;action=display;num=1112480053)